# Interpretation for Coefficients in Logistic Regression after Using One-Hot Encoder

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, categorical-data

Recently, I have read two articles saying we should avoid dropping one level of a categorical variable as the reference group while using both **one-hot encoder** and **regularization** in linear regression/logistic regression, otherwise there would be additional biases added to the model -
https://kiwidamien.github.io/are-you-getting-burned-by-one-hot-encoding.html; https://inmachineswetrust.com/posts/drop-first-columns/

So I am wondering how can we interpret the meaning of the coefficients if we don't "create" any reference groups by dropping one level of each categorical variable (use of **one-hot encoder**) and still use **l2 regularization** in logistic regression?

My question would be:

1). (In the above context) Can we interpret the coefficients as the magnitude of the "general" contribution from each variable to the log odds of y, even though there would be no comparison within each categorical variable group.

2). After we standardize the coefficients of a logistic regression model by multiplying each coefficient by it's respective X's standard deviation, can we really compare the "impact" of a categorical variable with that of a numerical variable? And how can we interpret the coefficient of a categorical variable after standardization.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_linear_model_coefficient_interpretation.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a great question. I agree with your approach, but don't see a clear road to interpretation. :)